# Can you (native speakers) see the difference between "I wish he wouldn't make noise" and "I wish he didn't make noise"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

That is what I learn from English grammar books

"I wish he wouldn't make noise" means he is making noise or he often makes noise and I don't like that and I wish he changed his behavior.

"I wish he didn't make noise" means he is making noise or he often makes noise and I merely wish he did differently but that sentence doesn't say if I like or don't like his behavior

But **I don't know how do native speakers think about these 2 sentences?**

Comment: If you 'wish he did differently', you certainly don't like it! (But it suggests a preference rather than annoyance at the noise.)

Comment: Very similar, but 'wouldn't' conveys more suggestion of doing it on purpose, whereas 'didn't' suggests he can't help it. If he's humming along to headphones while working at his PC: 'wouldn't', if his shoes squeak while he's walking (normally) along the office corridor: 'didn't'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with "*wish...wouldn't*", there's a slight nuance of annoyance, whereas  "*wish...didn't*" doesn't have that nuance. So a proficient speaker would prefer "wouldn't" when they're annoyed, and "didn't" when they're not annoyed. To be clear, it isn't a rule of English, just a preference.

Comment: +1 As an AmE I agree! :3